# Getting : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'input_text' on Robot Framework new Keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to add a new keyword to my Robot Framework Library, the keyword Should Enter a date in a text box.

Here is my keyword definition :

```
def type_in_arrival_box(self, txt):
    self.input_text("arrival date", txt)    
    return self
```

First Problem was that I am getting a unicode error so I have used Evaluate keyword to convert my parameter to a String when calling the keyword :

```
${text} =  Evaluate  'id=spArrival'
Type In Arrival Box  ${text}  10/09/2015
```

I am not getting the unicode error anymore however I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'input_text'
```

I am not sure what this error means any help please?

Comment: Is that the actual code? How are you calling it? Remove anything about problems you no longer have, it's a distraction (c:

Comment: Thx , I al calling the pyhton code through the keyword : Type In Arrival Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `self` is a string, which likely means that you've incorrectly defined the keyword. Since the first parameter is `self`, the keyword needs to be in a class, and that class needs to have the same name as the file it is in (minus the .py suffix).

If you never intended to use classes, remove the `self` parameter from the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer It was meant to be in a class and indeed there was a typo in my class name. Cheers!